# Does child object implement parent classes interface?

Tags: c#, object, interface

This may have been asked before but I couldnt find a satisfactory answer:

I have an interface called `IRepository` that defines a lot of generic methods such as `Find<T>();`

I have an abstract class called `RepositoryBase` that implements this interface providing generic versions of these methods.

I then have a series of objects that inherit from this object such as `PersonRepository`.

my question is:

**Is the PersonRepository an object of type IRepository?**

or in other words will this code work?

```
IRepository repo = new PersonRepository();
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  (Spoiler - the answer is "yes")

Comment: just out of curiosity... what did the compiler do when you tried it?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: Because at the moment I am on holiday with no access to my Visual Studio and I am merely contemplating the finer points of object orientation!

Comment: Fair enough.  http://ideone.com is a decent tool for testing small hypotheses like that one.

Comment: @StevenWood This isn't a finer point.  It's one of the key tenants of OOP.  If you couldn't be bothered to simply try it out, it would have been sufficient to do any basic amount of research into the topic to find the answer as well.

Comment: Whoah! a little less attitude if you please, I am simply asking a question that occured to me which is not obvious without having actually tried it.

Comment: @StevenWood - Actually, that's sort of his point. I tend to prefer to to help people, but part of the etiquette of posting to SO is that askers should have done some basic research on their own. It's trivial for you to check this yourself - many of the tools are free, or if you'd prefer to not download something, there are even online snippit runners. Keep in mind that half the purpose of SO is to build a database of useful questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes

Since, `PersonRepository` inherits from `RepositoryBase` which is an abstract class implementing `IRepository`, so an instance of `PersonRepository` also implements `IRepository`

Answer (score 0):

Unqualified yes. Inheritance is a single-path chain. Subclasses may override functionality from parent classes, or hide it with their own functionality, but they are not allowed to 'unimplement' it.

Comment: Both antiduh and amitJokis answers are good but as AmitJoki answered first I will accept his answer. Thanks for answering.